# Handling keyboard events in python

Tags: python, keyboard-events

How can I handle keyboard events in python? More exactly I need to manage keyboard arrows and some other keys for my command-line application.
Is there a module for this or I need to handle key by key using for example "if get(key)==(mykey): do something" (it's pseudo-code)?
I'm on Gnu/Linux OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for a python [(n)curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) library. This will allow to "get around" your terminal buffering and work with key-presses directly.

Comment: Thanks. I had already thought of something about curses and you confirmed me.

Answer (score 3):

Would the [cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) module suit your needs?  It handles command-line history through the arrow keys, for instance, as well as completion.

If you need to catch a single key, there is a cross-platform [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/) for this (see also [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) on StackOverflow).

Comment: It seems I need cmd module too :) thanks. I clicked your answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

jkerian's `curses` suggestion is a good one, and is the one to use if you're working with Unix/Linux/etc. (which you are), but if you ever end up working in a Windows environment, then you'll definitely want to check out [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) and its `win32con` module, which wraps the Windows API's Console functions and structs.

Answer (score 0):

I found another interesting module that's straightforward to use and I'll use it! The module is readline and you just need to import it to have a bash shell (handle keyboard, history-list, etc) "simulation". It's for *nix systems. I'm at beginning with python language and I don't know all modules yet. [readline](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html)